# DELETE FROM with named subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, sql-delete

I have a SQL query that looks like this:

```
DELETE
    price.*
FROM
    price
JOIN
    service
ON
    price.service_id = service.id
WHERE
    price.country_from_id NOT IN
        (SELECT
            country_id
        FROM
            carrier_zone_country
        JOIN
            carrier_zone
        ON
            carrier_zone_id = carrier_zone.id
        WHERE
            carrier_zone.carrier_service_id = service.carrier_service_id)
    OR
    price.country_to_id NOT IN
        (SELECT
            country_id
        FROM
            carrier_zone_country
        JOIN
            carrier_zone
        ON
            carrier_zone_id = carrier_zone.id
        WHERE
            carrier_zone.carrier_service_id = service.carrier_service_id)
```

I was hoping to avoid running the subquery twice by moving it into the `FROM` clause and giving it a name. However, that gave me syntax errors. Looking at the documentation, I can see that only the `SELECT FROM` clause can have a named subquery in it.

Firstly I am wondering why that is the case? And secondly, how could I re-write this SQL query to avoid performing the same subquery twice.

Comment: Do a NOT EXISTS, where you check both price.country_from_id  and price.country_to_id.

Comment: is it mysql or sqlserver?

Comment: @Deepshikha, why do you suspect SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh Could you perhaps explain a bit more how to use `NOT EXISTS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one single `NOT EXISTS` sub-query, where both to and from countries are checked:

```
DELETE
    price.*
FROM
    price
JOIN
    service
ON
    price.service_id = service.id
WHERE
NOT EXIST(SELECT
            1
        FROM
            carrier_zone_country
        JOIN
            carrier_zone
        ON
            carrier_zone_id = carrier_zone.id
        WHERE country_id IN (price.country_from_id, price.country_to_id)
          AND carrier_zone.carrier_service_id = service.carrier_service_id))
```

Comment: My current query will delete records if `country_from_id` or `country_to_id` do not exist, this will only delete records if both `country_from_id` *and* `country_to_id` do not exist, will it not?

Comment: It's supposed to delete if country_from_id or country_to_id do not exist. But you'd better try it before going into production.

Comment: I changed the subquery to a `COUNT` and then check if that is less than 2. Now it works, thanks.